# react-native: how to make keyboard on top of the component?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

I have a bottomSheet component and when the keyboard is open the view of the bottomSheet get round.

The component without opening keyboard:
[image]

but when keybored is opened:
[image]

component code:

```
<BottomSheet
            visible={isOpen}
            onBackButtonPress={() => {
                setToUpdate(undefined)
                setIsOpen(false);
            }}
        >
            <View style={[buttomSheetStyles.bottomNavigationView, { height: "80%", backgroundColor: Colors.white500 }]}>
                <View style={[buttomSheetStyles.buttomSheetContainer, { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around' }]}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/return.png')} resizeMode='contain' style={{ position: 'absolute', top: -100 }} />
                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 80 }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'almarai-bold' : 'montserrat-bold', fontSize: 17, textAlign: 'center' }}>{t("returnsScreen:NewReturnHeader")}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Formik
                        validationSchema={returnValidationSchema}
                        initialValues={(toUpdate === undefined) ?
                            { packageQuantity: '', unitQuantity: '', cause: '', image: '' } :
                            { packageQuantity: toUpdate.value.productQuantity.packageQuantity.toString(), unitQuantity: toUpdate.value.productQuantity.unitQuantity.toString(), cause: toUpdate.value.cause, image: toUpdate.value.image.fileContent }}
                        onSubmit={(values) => {
                            console.log(values.cause)
                            if (toUpdate === undefined)
                                onSubmit(values);
                            else
                                onSubmit(values, toUpdate.index);
                            setToUpdate(undefined)
                        }}
                    >
                        {({
                            handleChange,
                            handleBlur,
                            handleSubmit,
                            setValues,
                            setFieldValue,
                            touched,
                            values,
                            errors,
                            isValid,
                            dirty,
                        }) => (
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                                <View
                                    style={{
                                        flex: 1,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
                                        <Text style={{ flex: 2.5, textAlign: 'left', paddingLeft: 10, color: Colors.primary500, fontFamily: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'almarai-regular' : 'montserrat-regular' }}>{t("common:products")}</Text>
                                        <Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', color: Colors.primary500, fontFamily: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'almarai-regular' : 'montserrat-regular' }}>{t("common:package")}</Text>
                                        <Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: 'center', color: Colors.primary500, fontFamily: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'almarai-regular' : 'montserrat-regular' }}>{t("common:units")}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{
                                        flex: 3, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flexDirection: 'row'
                                    }}>
                                        <CachedImage
                                            source={{
                                                uri: `${env.apiUrl.concat(env.productImagePngById.replace(":productId", orderItem.product!.id)).concat("?thumbnail=true")}`, // (required) -- URI of the image to be cached
                                                expiresIn: 43200, // 12 hours in seconds (optional), if not set -- will never expire and will be managed by the OS
                                            }}
                                            cacheKey={`${orderItem.product!.id}-thumbnail`} // (required) -- key to store image locally
                                            placeholderContent={( // (optional) -- shows while the image is loading
                                                <Image
                                                    source={{
                                                        uri: productDefaultImage
                                                    }}
                                                    resizeMode="contain"
                                                    style={{ width: 100, height: 70 }}
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            resizeMode="contain" // pass-through to <Image /> tag
                                            style={{ width: 100, height: 70 }}
                                        />
                                        <View style={{ flex: 5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                            <View style={{ flex: 5, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', marginStart: 7 }}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.nameStyleText}>{I18nManager.isRTL ? orderItem.product!.rtlName : orderItem.product!.name}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={{ flex: 1.5, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                                    <Input
                                                        style={{ alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: Colors.white500 }}
                                                        value={values.packageQuantity.toString()}
                                                        onChangeText={handleChange('packageQuantity')}
                                                        status={
                                                            touched.packageQuantity
                                                                ? !errors.packageQuantity
                                                                    ? "success"
                                                                    : "danger"
                                                                : "warning"
                                                        }
                                                        keyboardType="numeric"
                                                    />
                                                    <Input
                                                        style={{ alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: Colors.white500 }}
                                                        value={values.unitQuantity.toString()}
                                                        onChangeText={handleChange('unitQuantity')}
                                                        status={
                                                            touched.unitQuantity
                                                                ? !errors.unitQuantity
                                                                    ? "success"
                                                                    : "danger"
                                                                : "warning"
                                                        }
                                                        keyboardType="numeric"
                                                    />
                                                </View>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ flex: 0.5, borderColor: Colors.black900, borderWidth: 1 }}>
                                    <Picker
                                        prompt={t("common:selectReason")}
                                        mode="dropdown"
                                        selectedValue={values.cause}
                                        onValueChange={(e) => {
                                            console.log("e: ", e)
                                            setFieldValue('cause', e)
                                        }
                                        }>
                                        <Picker.Item enabled={false} label={t("common:selectReason")} value={``} />
                                        <Picker.Item label={t("returnsScreen:DAMAGED")} value={ReturnProductEnum.DAMAGED} />
                                        <Picker.Item label={t("returnsScreen:UNLOADED")} value={ReturnProductEnum.UNLOADED} />
                                        <Picker.Item label={t("returnsScreen:EXPIRED")} value={ReturnProductEnum.EXPIRED} />
                                    </Picker>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                                    <CameraInput
                                        imageCallback={handleChange("image")}
                                        openCamera={isCameraOpen}
                                        setOpenCamera={setIsCameraOpen}
                                        status={errors.image}
                                        image={values.image}
                                    />
                                </View>
                                <Button
                                    style={{
                                        flex: 0.5,
                                        width: '100%',
                                        borderRadius: 9,
                                        height: 65,
                                        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
                                    }}
                                    status='info'
                                    disabled={!isValid || !dirty || loading}
                                    onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
                                    accessoryRight={loading ? <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}><Spinner size='small' status='info' /></View> : IconComponent(
                                        (I18nManager.isRTL ? evaIcons.backArrow : evaIcons.frontArrow),
                                        Colors.white500
                                    )}
                                >
                                    {(props) => (
                                        <Text
                                            {...props}
                                            style={{
                                                fontFamily: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'almarai-bold' : 'montserrat-bold',
                                                color: Colors.white500,
                                                fontSize: 17,
                                                marginLeft: 35,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {t("common:submit")}
                                        </Text>
                                    )}
                                </Button>
                            </View>
                        )}
                    </Formik>
                </View>
            </View>
        </BottomSheet >
```

is there's any way I can make keyboard, on top of the bottomSheet?
or a way to make the bottomsheet scrollable...
or if there's any better way to atchive the same result ?